# Gradle EAR generation - application.xml

Tags: java, gradle, ear

I need to use the existing application.xml in my Project/META-INF/, but gradle generates 2 application.xml files.

I'm using this code:

```
ear {
     into("META-INF") {
        from("META-INF")
     }
}
```

Gradle generates 2 application.xml, the existing and a new that are wrong.
If i tried to exclude the application.xml, it excludes the existing.

How can i solve?

Comment: You have to files with the same name in the generated artifact?

Comment: Yes correct, gradle generates 1 new application.xml and also put the existing application.xml.

Comment: Any solution to this? I am having the same issue